How can I avoid text only homepage loading?
I'm new to wordpress, using the Astra theme and a Starter Template. Sometimes my website drnickhayward.com loads as text only like this:

This occurs randomly, not linked to recent page updates (I've made none for days) and my hosting service Ionos does not know what or why it's occurring.
Any help would be very much appreciated please. Thank you so much for your expertise.
Nick
Hi all, thank you so much. I really appreciate your help because FOUC keeps occurring and no one is sure why at Ionos. They do provide caching, so that's good, and I've removed WP super cache. I have used query monitor and there are some red lines connecting to an ionos server. Are any of you able to see that? I'll share a screenshot as I think it might be the Flash of unstyled content (FOUC) cause. I'm trying Autoptimize as well.

Thank you so much!

This is called Flash of unstyled content (FOUC) and could have MANY reasons...check the resources on this page:  https://superuser.com/questions/368041/why-do-webpages-sometimes-appear-as-plain-html-before-a-refresh

if you're using an optimisation/minifying plugin to serve css, and that plugin takes too long to do its job then no stylesheet/css gets delivered and your site appears completely unstyled like in that screenshot. However without reproducing the issue it's hard if not impossible to tell from just the information provided what the issue is. Do you have logs from the browser dev tools error console from when this happens? Likewise is there anything in your PHP error log? What do popular debugging plugins such as query monitor say?

Thank you both! My hosting service is looking into it too. I'll also check query monitor. Your responses and links are very very helpful - much appreciated!

I see you are using WP-Super-Cache so it could be an issue with the CSS optimization by this plugin (as mentioned by @TomJNowell) - one thing I wanted to mention is that pretty much all the top quality WordPress hosting solutions (WPEngine, Kinsta, Pagely, SiteGround...etc) all have built-in caching for WordPress and caching plugins are not needed. I strongly recommend using managed WP hosting solutions with built-in cache instead of having to use 3rd party plugins for this. Generally when I see a site using a caching plugin it's because they are on a budget hosting plan.

Hi all, thank you so much. I really appreciate your help because FOUC keeps occurring and no one is sure why at Ionos. They do provide caching, so that's good, and I've removed WP super cache. I have used query monitor and there are some red lines connecting to an ionos server. Are any of you able to see that? I'll share a screenshot as I think it might be the Flash of unstyled content (FOUC) cause. I'm trying Autoptimize as well.

I see you shared a screenshot in the backend of some errors with the ionos-sso plugin. Unfortunately this isn't helpful since your issue is with the live site. What you'll need to do is try and recreate the error with your browser console open in the "network" tab to see what errors show up. I've personally tried refreshing your site over and over and can never recreate the issue. If your hosting or no one else can replicate the issue it could be on your end.
